# Implementation of rxjs BehaviourSubject in Next.js for state management not working

Tags: node.js, rxjs, jwt, state-management

Trying to store jwt token on login using rxjs behavioursubject
Then creating a http request with Authorization: `Bearer ${user.jwtToken}` in the
I believe I need to have
a) initial value,
b) a source that can be turned into an observable
c) a public variable that can be subscribed

On log in the user is correctly added to the user subject here "userSubject.next(user);"
But whenever I try to create the bearer token its always null

```
// The Accounts Service

// initialise and set initial value
const userSubject = new BehaviorSubject(null);
const authApiUrl = "https:testApi";

export const accountService = {
```

`   user: userSubject.asObservable(), get userValue() { return userSubject.value },
login,
getAllUsers
};

```
function login(email, password) {
return fetchWrapper.post(process.env.AuthApiUrl + '/accounts/authenticate', { email, password                                })
    .then(user => {
        userSubject.next(user);
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
        return user;
    });
}

function getAllUsers() {
return await fetchWrapper.get(process.env.AuthApiUrl + '/accounts/get-all-users');
}
```

}

```
// The fetchwrapper
export const fetchWrapper = {
get,
post
};

function post(url, body) {
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', ...authHeader(url) },
    credentials: 'include',
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
};
return fetch(url, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
}

function get(url) {
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: authHeader(url)
};
return fetch(url, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
}

function authHeader(url) {
// return auth header with basic auth credentials if user is logged in and request is to the         api url

// THE accountService.userValue IS ALWAYS NULL???
const user = accountService.userValue;
const isLoggedIn = user && user.jwtToken;
const isApiUrl = url.startsWith(process.env.AuthApiUrl);
if (isLoggedIn && isApiUrl) {
    return { Authorization: `Bearer ${user.jwtToken}` };
} else {
    return {};
}
}

function handleResponse(response) {
return response.text().then(text => {
const data = text && JSON.parse(text);

    if (!response.ok) {
        if ([401, 403].includes(response.status) && accountService.userValue) {
            // auto logout if 401 Unauthorized or 403 Forbidden response returned from api
            accountService.logout();
        }

        const error = (data && data.message) || response.statusText;
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }

    return data;
});
```

}

Comment: How are you getting an instance of the accountService? If you just use a JavaScript import you are not getting the same instance of the service between components.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this blog post to see RxJs in Next.js in action: https://medium.com/p/e37d74dc94f4

Create eventBus.js with:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

const eventBus = new Subject();

export default eventBus;
```

In your component A:

```
import React from 'react';
import eventBus from '../path/to/eventBus';

const ComponentA = () => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    eventBus.next({ type: 'ACTION_FROM_COMPONENT_A', data: 'Hello from Component A!' });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Trigger Action</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ComponentA;
```

In your component B:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import eventBus from '../path/to/eventBus';

const ComponentB = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = 
    eventBus.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event.type === 'ACTION_FROM_COMPONENT_A') {
        setMessage(event.data);
      }
    });

    return () => {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Received message: {message}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ComponentB;
```

It works with all kinds on Subjects.